# SQL Server split time interval to multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, split

I have the following SQL Server tables.

```
CREATE TABLE workingSchedule 
  (
      [workingDate] DATETIME NULL,
      [openTime]       TIME (7) NULL,
      [closeTime]      TIME (7) NULL
  );

INSERT INTO workingSchedule
(workingDate, openTime, closeTime)
VALUES
('10/1/2015','9:00','17:00'),
('10/2/2015','9:00','17:00');

CREATE TABLE breakTable 
  (
  [breakDate] DATETIME NULL,
  [breakStart] TIME NULL,
  [breakEnd] TIME NULL
  );

INSERT INTO breakTable
(breakDate, breakStart, breakEnd)
VALUES
('10/1/2015','12:00','13:00'),
('10/1/2015','15:00','15:30'),
('10/2/2015','12:00','13:00');
```

I am trying to split the time intervals in [workingSchedule] into several rows considering the [breakTable]. The result I desire looks like this:

```
Date          Start    End 
10/1/2015     09:00    12:00
10/1/2015     13:00    15:00
10/1/2015     15:30    17:00
10/2/2015     09:00    12:00
10/2/2015     13:00    17:00
```

I am not sure if I should use CTE, a function, or temporary tables. I appreciate if you can share your solution code. I was able to split time interval when there is only one break, but I failed when it came to multiple break times per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like this, I use ROW_NUMBER (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to help join splits inside a single day. I used a UNION, but I think you could use the same join logic I have, but get away with a SELECT statement.

```
SELECT  workingDate as [date], openTime as [Start], COALESCE(breakStart, closeTime) as [End]
FROM    workingSchedule
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT  breakDate,  breakStart, breakEnd, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY breakDate ORDER BY breakStart) AS ROWNUM
            FROM    breakTable
        ) as firstBreak ON workingSchedule.workingDate = firstBreak.breakDate AND firstBreak.ROWNUM = 1
UNION
SELECT  breakStart.breakDate, breakStart.breakEnd, coalesce(breakEnd.breakStart, endTime.closeTime)
FROM    (
            SELECT  breakDate,  breakStart, breakEnd, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY breakDate ORDER BY breakStart) AS ROWNUM
            FROM    breakTable
        ) as breakStart
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT  breakDate,  breakStart, breakEnd, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY breakDate ORDER BY breakStart) AS ROWNUM
            FROM    breakTable
        ) as breakEnd ON breakStart.breakDate = breakEnd.breakDate AND breakStart.ROWNUM = breakEnd.ROWNUM - 1
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT  workingDate, closeTime
            FROM    workingSchedule
        ) AS endTime ON breakStart.breakDate = endTime.workingDate
```

The idea here is to pull the start time, and the first break if there is one. If there is no break, the COALESCE will pull the closeTime instead. We then union on the breaks throughout the day. Finally, we join the closeTime onto the final break, again using COALESCE to use the closeTime when there is no "breakEnd.breakStart".

Here's a SQL Fiddler of it in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a4765/14

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly for my question. When I tried to add extra break time in the day, the results turned as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this


DECLARE @Tab TABLE
(
[Date] [datetime],
[Time] [time],
[Row] int
)

DECLARE @Tab2 TABLE
(
[Date] [datetime],
[Row] int
)

INSERT INTO @Tab2
SELECT DISTINCT(workingDate) , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [workingDate])
FROM workingSchedule 

DECLARE @Count int;
DECLARE @Num [int];
DECLARE @Dat [datetime];
SET @Num=1;
SET @Count=(SELECT count(*) FROM @Tab2 t)

WHILE @Num<=@Count
BEGIN
SET @Dat=(SELECT [Date] FROM @Tab2 t WHERE t.[Row]=@Num)

INSERT INTO @Tab
SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY Cte4.breakStart) Number  FROM  (
SELECT *  FROM(
SELECT Cte.breakDate, Cte.breakStart  FROM 
(SELECT * FROM breakTable 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM workingSchedule
)Cte 
WHERE Cte.breakDate=@Dat  
)Cte2

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM(
SELECT Cte.breakDate, Cte.breakEnd  FROM 
(SELECT * FROM breakTable 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM workingSchedule
)Cte 
WHERE Cte.breakDate=@Dat
)Cte3
)Cte4
ORDER BY Cte4.breakStart
SET @Num=@Num+1;
END
;WITH Cte AS
(
SELECT * FROM @Tab t
WHERE t.[Row]%2=0
),
 Cte2 AS
(
SELECT * FROM @Tab t
WHERE t.[Row]%2=1
)
SELECT  DISTINCT Cte.[Date],Cte2.[Time] AS Start, Cte.[Time] AS [End] FROM Cte
INNER JOIN
Cte2 
ON
(Cte2.[Row]+1)=Cte.[Row]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the query to get desired output

```
;WITH CTEOrderedBreaks
AS
(
  SELECT row_number() over(partition by breakdate order by breakdate,breakstart asc) as rnob,
         row_number() over(partition by breakdate order by breakdate,breakstart DESC) as rnobr,
         breakdate,
         breakstart,
         breakend
  from breakTable
 ),
 CTESUMMARY
 AS
 (
   SELECT WS.WORKINGDATE,WS.OPENTIME AS [START],COB.BREAKSTART AS [END]
   FROM CTEOrderedBreaks COB INNER JOIN WORKINGSCHEDULE WS ON WS.WORKINGDATE = COB.breakdate
   WHERE COB.RNOB=1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COB1.BREAKDATE,COB1.BREAKEND AS [START],ISNULL(COB2.BREAKSTART,WS1.CLOSETIME)AS [END]
   FROM CTEOrderedBreaks COB1 
   left JOIN CTEOrderedBreaks COB2 ON COB1.RNOB = COB2.RNOB-1 
                                           AND COB1.BREAKDATE = COB2.BREAKDATE
   LEFT JOIN workingSchedule WS1 ON WS1.WORKINGDATE = COB1.BREAKDATE AND COB1.RNOBR=1
 )

 SELECT * FROM CTESUMMARY 
 ORDER BY WORKINGDATE,START
```

Here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4076a/21

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly for my question as well. this approach is great as well.

Comment: I am Glad that i could help! :)

Comment: This will not work if you have a day without any breaks.

Answer (score -1):

```
create table #answer
(workdate datetime null,
    starttime time null,
    endtime time null
)
declare cur cursor for (select workingDate,openTime,closeTime from workingSchedule)
declare @workingDate datetime,@openTime time,@closeTime time,@breakStart time,@breakEnd time,@breakEnd2 time,@counter int
set @counter = 0;
open cur
fetch cur into @workingDate,@openTime,@closeTime
while(@@FETCH_STATUS =0)
begin
declare cur2 cursor for select breakStart,breakEnd from breakTable  where breakDate = @workingDate order by breakStart
open cur2
fetch cur2 into @breakStart,@breakEnd
set @counter = 1;
while(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
begin
if(@counter = 1)
begin
    insert into #answer values(@workingDate,@openTime,@breakStart)
end
else
begin
insert into #answer values(@workingDate,@breakEnd2,@breakStart)
end
set @breakEnd2 = @breakEnd
set @counter = @counter+1;


fetch cur2 into @breakStart,@breakEnd

end
close cur2
deallocate cur2
fetch cur into @workingDate,@openTime,@closeTime
end
close cur
deallocate cur
select * from #answer
drop table #answer
```

the resault is :

```
2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 09:00:00.0000000    12:00:00.0000000
2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 13:00:00.0000000    15:00:00.0000000
2015-10-02 00:00:00.000 09:00:00.0000000    12:00:00.0000000
```

Answer (score -1):

```
;with cte as(
             select *, row_number() over(partition by wd order by ot) rn
             from
                (select workingDate wd, openTime ot from workingSchedule
                 union
                 select workingDate, closeTime from workingSchedule
                 union
                 select breakDate, breakStart from breakTable
                 union
                 select breakDate, breakEnd from breakTable)t)
select c1.wd, c1.ot, c2.ot
from cte c1
join cte c2 on c1.wd = c2.wd and c1.rn + 1 = c2.rn and c1.rn % 2 = 1
order by c1.wd, c1.ot
```

Idea is to produce ordered times for date and then joining first row on second, third on fourth etc...

Comment: If you have two breaks where one starts when the other ends it will not be correct.